Is there a fast matrix-free inverse power iteration?
Problem: I want to solve the eigenvalue problem
$$x=Ax$$
to the eigenvalue $1$ for a large matrix (roughly $N^3\times N^3$ and $N$ ranges from 10 to 100) where $A$ is stochastic (i.e. all entries are non-negative and row sum =1) and sparse (at most 10 entries per row are non-zero).
However, $A$ is not explicitly given (but the product $Av$ for some vector $v$ is given) and I think it's cumbersome and inefficient to build and store such a matrix.
Therefore, I decided to use the power iteration
$$x_{k+1}=Ax_k$$
which works, but converges really slowly. I read that the inverse iteration
$$y_{k+1}=(A-\mu I)^{-1}y_k$$
for some $\mu$ close to 1 could converge faster, but since I don't have $A$ itself, I don't know how to compute $(A-I)^{-1}$.
I have hardly any experience with such iterative methods or large/sparse matrix techniques which is why I'm asking:
Question 1: Is there a matrix-free inverse iteration suitable for this problem?
Question 2: Is there another trick (some preconditioning) to speed up the power iteration?
Question 3: Is there a more efficient technique that could solve this system?
Any help or comment is greatly appreciated!

For the inversion just solve problems of the form $(A-\mu I) y_{k+1} = y_k$ with some iterative solver. You can use some preconditioner for the iterative solver yes. You can also look into Arnoldi ir Lanczos iterations for the estimation of eigenvalues.

Maybe try solving $(A-I)x=0$ with a sparse direct solver (e.g MUMPS) or an iterative solver (e.g. GMRES). Maybe you will not need a preconditionner if the eigenvalues are all clustered, which might be the case here ?

lightxbulb and @Laurent90 thank you for your comments, I'll try to apply the algorithms you suggested. Concerning the eigenvalues, all I can say (at least I think so....) is that 1 is the largest eigenvalue (Perron-Frobenius). Using $\mu=1$ would cause divergence. My concern is that using $\mu<1$ could cause the iteration to converge to another close eigenvalue/vector. Is this a valid concern?  Moreover, I read that solving $(A-I)x=0$ could be difficult because methods tend to find the trivial solution $x=0$ (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410566/matrix-free-linear-solve-for-nullspace)

ARPACK is an eigenvalue solver that does not require anything other than the action of a matrix. SLEPc can also handle matrices that are only provided via their action.

You might look into LOBPCG, I have had better luck with it than Lanczos/Arnoldi methods when it comes to finding small eigenpairs / inverse iteration. I would imagine it's not too hard to incorporate some shifting.
